# Grafana with ElasticSearch: using plugins to manipulate the database

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, grafana

I just started playing around with grafana and elastic search. I want to have grafana use an elasticsearch data-source, and I want to build a rule based system on top of it (so, for example: if ice_cream_count < 100 and fridge_space > 200 then I need to fill up fridge.)

In Elastic database, I will have a variable for ice_cream_count and a variable for fridge_space, and I know that I can use a python script to create the rule based system, put result into elastic, and then put a pretty visualization in grafana (and this seems to be the intended use for the app.)

But then I thought: wouldn't it be nice if I could add rules using a grafana plugin. I am new to this library, so I guess my question is: would I be terribly misguided if I said that plugins are just some javascript with CSS/html, and I can listen for user event as I would when writing a website, and then add the rules themselves to the Elasticsearch database, and then write a plugin that will query for those rules and execute them on top of other fields in Elastic search?

I guess I am asking if someone with more experience than I have would advise doing the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible. There is a plugin for administrating an InfluxDB data source that is similar in that it allows you to execute queries and insert data into the db: https://grafana.com/plugins/natel-influx-admin-panel. There are a couple of apps that also do more than just querying data.

Comment: Thank you! That example is enormously useful.